# Use If exists for select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am creating a view  and written the below code snippet :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vclPersonData
    AS
SELECT * FROM phone_data UNION 
SELECT * FROM Address
```

I get an error if the table doesn't exists, to come overthat i used If Exists but it too doesn't works for me.

Any help is thankful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need two steps in your script:

1. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`
2. `CREATE VIEW AS SELECT * FROM TABLE`

If the table exists, step 1 will be harmless. If the table does not exist, step 1 will create it and step 2 will create an empty view.

If you only want the view to be created IF the table exist, check the existance of the table before:

```
BEGIN
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE;
CREATE VIEW AS SELECT * FROM TABLE
COMMIT
```

Comment: I have to union 6 tables so i have to check that those tables exists or not , if not i have to create a one ...I there other way work around say that i dont have to create a table only skip union statement with the table that doesn't exists ?

Comment: You'll need a procedure for that, either a Stored Procedure on your MYSQL server, or a script. Could you explain what you are trying to do and how you are doing this, so we can further help you?